# Header not re-sizing when I make the window smaller

Tags: css

My header is a picture, so I can't use percentages. it has to be of fixed width and height.
with that, when I resize the window and make it smaller, the content of the page fits to the correct size, but the header stays the same (of course) thus, it overflows beyond the page's borders and adds a scroll bar at the bottom.

Can I cut, or crop, the header so its height is always fixed, and the width corresponds automatically with the fixed height, but that the overflow of the header out of the page's border's is hidden?

I can use

```
body {
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

but I fill that's cheating.
any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: That's perfectly fine to do.  You can also use percentages on either height or width and your image should keep it's aspect ratio - as long as you don't do both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're after... Make your header a div that fits 100% width x whatever height you require. Then set that div to have a background image and **overflow: hidden;**. That will always resize to fit your page width with no scroll bars.

```
div{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px; /* Set your height here */
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(http://www.f-covers.com/cover/beach-fun-vintage-photography-facebook-cover-timeline-banner-for-fb.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
```

This keeps the background image dimensions at the original size. If, however, you want the image to stretch to fit the div, add this to the css;

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AWMQ6/

Enjoy!

Comment: No worries Michael  :)